# How do I get the edit item menu from a search results page?

Tags: search, delete

One of our departments has a library that contains 150,000 documents, rendering the main library view pretty useless.  So I've created a search page for users to find documents, but there's no way to access menu items from the search results page.  We need to be able to modify properties, delete documents (most important), and see version history as well. Anyone know how to get these options to show in the search results page?

Comment: What version of SharePoint?

Comment: https://sharepointatwork.wordpress.com/2015/07/29/custom-context-menu-in-search-results-previewpane-using-display-templates-jsom/

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a couple things. First create better views. Group by metadata or use metadata navigation.

If you are using SharePoint 2013 the Library Search feature is what you are looking for. (Not available in 2010.)

If you still need a Search Results page to do what you want then you will have to create a new Display Template (in 2013) or modify the XSL of the search result (in 2010). Then you just add the links to the actions you seek.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. We are on 2013. Unfortunately the Library Search feature only seems to filter what is already shown in the view, so that doesn't really help much.  This library was created before I started and there is no useful metadata to speak of (and the library is now too big to add new columns!) I tried modifying the Display Template, but can't find a useful column (ID and DocumentID don't show anything) with which to create the link. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, the search should be for the whole library not the view (it's not a filter). Are you sure it's being crawled successfully? Can you migrate the content to a better library with appropriate columns?

Comment: If you're talking about the "Find a file" search box, then yes, I'm pretty sure it doesn't search the whole library, but rather only what is pulled up in the query of the view (not just what is visible at the moment).  So my view is limited to query < 2000 results so as not to exceed the threshold.  The crawl works fine because I've created a search page scoped to the library which brings up the results just fine.  Additionally, in cases where the file IS in the view, the "Find a file" search shows it.  However, the files NOT displayed in the view are not found.

Comment: Migrating to another library will be tricky, but I might try it (if I can get sign off to do so!). I think the best solution though would be to just add links to Edit and Delete files in the search results web part using Display Templates, but I still haven't been able to successfully create the link. I would need a unique ID but can't seem to find a property that works.